# Getting a segmentation fault on setting value for 2d array, even though for loop counter values are inside the sizeof of array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I am declaring and printing a simple 2d array or matrix.

I am getting a segmentation fault that is being caused by the nested for loop that sets the values of the matrix.

```
int rows, columns;
rows = columns = 3;

int **matrix;
matrix = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows);

for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns);
}
```

**This throws a seg fault**

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {            
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

**If I set i = 1, there is no seg. fault.**

```
for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {            
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

**However, it does make the first 3 values printed random though.**

### -------

**Entire Code**

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {


int rows, columns;
rows = 3;
columns = 3;

int **matrix;
matrix = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows);

for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns);
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {            
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {            
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        printf("%d\n", matrix[i][j]);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    free(matrix[i]);
}
free(matrix); 

return 1;

}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {` should be `rows`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
int **matrix;
matrix = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows);
```

You want `matrix` to be an array of **pointers to int** but you use "sizeof int" instead of "sizeof int pointer". Try:

```
int **matrix;
matrix = malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows);
```

or better

```
int **matrix;
matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof *matrix);
```

As pointed out by @n.m in a comment, the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns);
}
```

is wrong. It shall be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {   // Notice this change
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns);
}
```

Comment: @seamus This is not the only problem. The code works because `rows` is the same as `columns`. Try 3 rows and 30 columns.

Comment: @seamus On your system it's probably so that a pointer is 8 bytes and an int is 4 bytes. So when you use the wrong argument for sizeof you allocate too little memory for holding the pointers. You can try the following to see the size: `printf(pointer: %zu - int: %zu \n", sizeof(int*), sizeof(int));`